# Data type for binding x and y coordinates in AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an array of data consisting body parts detail and I am using Absolute Layout.
I only need to provide X and Y coordinates but I don’t want to provide width and height which should be taken automatically.

So, the question is, what should be the DATA TYPE, if we need to bind the X and Y coordinate. I am using list view to bind all those data.
eg.

AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.80, 0.193"

AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.4, 0.21"

[image: Code sample absolute layout preview]

Comment: I think the LayoutBounds is just a Rect, no?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.absolutelayout.setlayoutbounds?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_AbsoluteLayout_SetLayoutBounds_Xamarin_Forms_BindableObject_Xamarin_Forms_Rectangle_

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `LayoutBounds` as follow:

```
<ListView x:Name="EmployeeView" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <Label Text="I'm centered on iPhone 4 but no other device"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="{Binding rect1}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  />
            <Label Text="I'm bottom center on every device."
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="{Binding rect2}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  />

        </AbsoluteLayout>
      </DataTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And Bindable property should be a `Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle`

```
double x,y,width,height;
x= 100;
y=100;
width = 100;
height = 100;
Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle rect = new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle(x,y,width,height);

Employees employees = new Employees();
employees.rect = rect;
EmployeeView.ItemsSource = employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

When using position proportional, you can let the width and height autosize.

`AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.4,0.21,-1,-1"`